# Are there any accounts on "hyper-multigraphs"?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

Two generalizations of graphs have been described in a number of articles: multigraphs and hypergraphs. A [multigraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multigraph) is a graph in which multiple or parallel edges between nodes are allowed. These edges have the same end nodes.

A [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) is a graph in which an edge can join any number of vertices. An edge can therefore connect sets of multiple nodes to one another.

Both concepts allow one to model relations among objects with more detail and precision than with 'ordinairy' graphs. However, I have yet to find an account in which a combination of both structures is described: the *hyper-multigraph*. Such a graph would allow for parallel edges between the sets of nodes.

> **Question**: are there any references on such hyper-multigraphs?

Comment: try "multi-hypergraph" instead or "(multi-)hypergraph". These things get referred to from time to time, but it's not like anyone is going to write a whole paper about the subject.

Answer (score 0):

In the applications I'm familiar with, there isn't a meaningful distinction between e.g. unweighted multigraphs and standard weighted graphs with integer edge weights. In other words, the identity of the edges is not particularly important, only the number of them having the same endpoints. Weighted graphs of course generalize this notion to non-integer weights.

In the same way, you can treat multiple hyperedges with identical vertices as a single weighted hyperedge, and there's a wealth of information available about*weighted* hypergraphs that are likely directly applicable to any problem like the one you mention.

If that particular interpretation of multiple hyperedges isn't sensible for what you have in mind, we'll need some more information about what properties/behavior of the construction are of interest.